# Displaying Expenses under each expense type using MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have two tables that I am creating a list that shows all the expenses under each expense type. I have been able to get it to work except when I add the

> AND WHERE expenses.pid = " . $pid

it cases a Syntax error and I can't figure out way.

The biggest thing is I need to limet the Expense Type to only show the ones that have some data to go below them

```
EXPENSETYPE
typeid           
pid          
exptype 

EXPENSES
expid            
pid              
expdate          
checktype            
payee            
typeid       
details          
amount 






<?php
$pid = 6;

$sql = "SELECT expensetype.typeid, expensetype.exptype
        FROM `expensetype` WHERE expensetype.pid = $pid
        ORDER BY expensetype.typeid DESC";
$expensetype = $db->query($sql);
foreach($expensetype as $type) {

    echo '<li>' . $type['exptype'] . '<ul>';

    $sql2 = "SELECT expenses.expid, expenses.expdate, expenses.checktype, expenses.payee, expenses.details, expenses.amount
            FROM `expenses` WHERE `expenses`.typeid = " . $type['typeid'] . "AND WHERE expenses.pid = " . $pid ; 
            $expenses = $db->query($sql2);
            foreach($expenses as $exp) {
        echo '<li>' . $exp['expdate'] . '   ' . $exp['checktype'] . '   ' . $exp['expdate'] . '   ' . $exp['payee'] . '   ' . $exp['details'] .'   ' . $exp['amount'] .'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul></li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You have to work on your question much harder. Make it readable (means no scrolling required) and post EXACT error message

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL statement instead of making two of them :

```
SELECT `expensetype`.`typeid`, `expensetype.exptype`, `expenses`.`expid`,
    `expenses`.`expdate`, `expenses`.`checktype`, `expenses`.`payee`,
    `expenses`.`details`, `expenses`.`amount`
FROM `expensetype` INNER JOIN `expenses` ON
    `expensetype`.`typeid` = `expense`.`typeid`
WHERE (...)
```

Also, you cannot use two `WHERE` in a SQL statement, only use `AND`.

Comment: Thanks that worked fine as soon as I fingered out how to use it in my script